# How do I defend against being charmed by enemies?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I'm currently fighting against groups that contain at least one Fampyr. The really annoying thing about this is that their opening move is charming one of my party members. They're also really, really good at it and succeed almost always.

I tried to use my priest to defend against it, but I misread the spells and only found one that worked against being confused and dazed, but nothing against being charmed.

My second idea was to use "suppress affliction" to remove the charmed effect, but that doesn't work either. Probably because it is classified as friendly AoE, and my charmed party member isn't friendly at that particular time.

What are effective methods to prevent my party members from being charmed?

Comment: Other than a high will to not get charmed in the first place?

Comment: @GodEmperorDune The Fampyrs attack with a high enough value that a small increase won't help, I need a pretty drastic effect (like the +50 defense the prayer against bewilderment provides against confusion).

Comment: @GodEmperorDune I just checked, they reliably charm Aloth who has 96 will. I understand the calcuation even less now, it showed something like 75 against 50 in the combat log. But the chance to charm seems just ridiculously high even against a character with high will

Comment: 75 against 50? That breaks all my knowledge of how I thought the save calculations worked (roll + attacker's accuracy vs roll + defender's save). I'm afraid I'm out of my depth here.

Comment: @GodEmperorDune It looks like it rolls with something like a -40 penalty against will, or it is using something other than will as the defense stat.

Comment: Will that temporary debuff-nullifying priest spell cancel it?

Answer (score 2):

Same Problem here. The one thing you can do is casting arcane reflection right from the start. Sometimes you are fast enough and that charm gets reflected (but with no effect on the fampyr).

Edit: after some tests, you can cast it every time perfectly if you put Aloth a little bit behind your first hero who will trigger the fight, so the enemy fampyr have to walk a bit before casting the charm.

I'm dealing with the fampyr using the cipher's puppet charm and at the end the priest can use this level 1 spell, concealing and protecting him for 20 more seconds (he can't do anything then).

One funny solution may be to run away with Aloth, as the Fampyr is really keen on charming *him*. The both of them were running around the map for minutes in one case :D

Edit²: Priests will get a spell on level 11 with a high defense against charm and domination :)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the attack details in the log, you'll see that the Fampyr's charm does not attack Will at all; it attacks Deflection, which is strange.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Is there any more depth you can provide to this answer, possibly charm stats and possibly more ways to do this?